# Generating a sine wave, hard-panning it to one speaker, and playing it with pyaudio

Tags: python, channel, pyaudio, panning

I downloaded Pyaudio and am trying to use it to generate binaural beats, but I'm having immense difficulty trying to figure out how to split each sine wave to it's own channel.  Essentially, I'd like to be able to hard-pan one sine wave to each ear to create a binaural beat effect.  Here's the code I was going off of:

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5    # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 2.0   # in seconds, may be float
f = 240.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively)
stream.write(volume*samples)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Alternatively, I've tried using sounddevice, which works well for panning, but I'm unable to create a sinewave that lasts any longer than a second.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what you tried with the `sounddevice` module?

Comment: I resolved the issue--sort of.  I just downloaded the AccelBrainBeat library, which generated binaural and monaural beats with a single line of code.